# How to create batch file for FFMpeg to download stream videos

Tags: batch-file, video, ffmpeg

Hi I'm using this cmd code to download stream video using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i "http://wpc.866f.edgecastcdn.net/03866F/greyback/yourtrinity/130929-webword_,2500,1500,580,265,.mp4.m3u8" -c copy 130929-webword.mkv
```

now I want a batch file that in running time ask me the video address and the file name by pressing Enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set /p "address=Video Address:"
set /p "filename=File name:"
ffmpeg -i "%address%" -c copy "%filename%"
```

Comment: I Created this batch file but when I run it, cmd immediately close the windows